# Смена базы данных при смене локализации приложения андроид

Tags: android, база-данных, локализация

Есть приложение типа справочник, в нём есть несколько оффлайн бд на разных языках. Как задать автоматический выбор бд на нужном языке исходя из языка устройства. Например если устройство на французком языке то при старте приложения запускается бд на французком, если английский то бд на английском.

```
import android.database.SQLException;
import 
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;


class DatabaseHelper extends 
SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static String DB_PATH; 
private static String DB_NAME =



getResources().getString(R.string.DBNAME); - getResource нельзч использовать в статик по этому не работает такой вариант
private static final int SCHEMA = 1; 
static final String TABLE = "users"; 
// названия столбцов
static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
static final String COLUMN_YEAR = "year";



private Context myContext;

DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, SCHEMA);
    this.myContext=context;
    DB_PATH =context.getFilesDir().getPath() + DB_NAME;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,  int newVersion) {
}

void create_db(){
    InputStream myInput = null;
    OutputStream myOutput = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(DB_PATH);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            String outFileName = DB_PATH;
            myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        Log.d("DatabaseHelper", ex.getMessage());
    }
}
public SQLiteDatabase open()throws SQLException {

    return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}
}
```

2 базы user_ru.db и user_en.db в папке assets

```
Values-ru/string.xml
<string name="DBNAME" tools:ignore="ExtraTranslation">user_ru.db</string>
```

Comment: Строковый ресурс с именем БД для каждого языка пропишите и будет все автоматически.

Comment: Можно подробнее о том что нужно написать в строковом ресурсе  или пример для любого языка

Comment: В values-ru пишете к примеру строку db_name со значением database_ru.db. Для немецкого в values_de -> database_de.db. Соответственно называете и сами файлы в assets. В приложении просто читаете db_name и строите путь для открытия БД. Не забудьте о значении по умолчанию.

Comment: В папке assets лежит 2 базы, user_en.db и user_ru.db, в values-ru  в файле string.xml прописал строку db_name = user_ru.db . В клласе DB_HELPER указал строку для db_name   при старье приложение слетает

Comment: private static String DB_NAME = getResource().getString(R.string.строка_из_ресурса); Такой вариант не работает.

Comment: зачем вы пытаетесь вызвать метод в блоке инициализации?  метод getResources() - метод класса Context, Вам нужно получать свое имя  в конструкторе класса, перед вызовом super(): `DB_NAME = context.getResources().getString(R.string.DBNAME);` , в блоке инициализации оставить только объявление этой переменной

Comment: Спасибо, всё получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Где хранятся сами бд и в каком формате? Если в ресурсах, то можно положить их в raw c соответствующими метками языка. Например, raw-ru-rRU для русского. Но это плохой вариант, т.к. на все языки вы положить по своей бд вы не сможете, а все неуказанные языки будут открывать ту базу, что лежи в папке raw, без указания локали. Кроме того, не всегда локаль на языке совпадет с желаемым языком словаря. Кто-то использует английскую прошивку на китайском смартфоне, потому что русской нет, и он не сможет воспользоваться вашим словарем.

Положите все локализации в папку raw или asset с разными именами для разных языков, при загрузке вытаскивайте локаль и открывайте ту базу, которая больше всего подойдет. И обязательно дайте возможность поменять локаль. А вообще хранить кучу дублирующих баз в apk моветон, зачем они на устройстве пользователю? Да еще и apk для загрузки в стор ограничен в 100мб. Положите их на сервер и скачивайте пр первом запуске те, которые попросит клиент

UPD.

Как я уже говорил, не стоит использовать инструменты локализации андроида для выбора базы базы. Вы же знаете имена ваших баз, вряд ли они изменятся. Можно "захардкодить" их в статические переменные. Сохраняйте путь до актуальной базы в SharedPreferences. Если в них нет пути или по нему нет файла - задаем вопрос юзеру, какой язык он хочет. Если уж очень хочется через локализацию андроида сделать - инициализируйте DB_NAME в конструкторе, нельзя обращаться к ресурсам из статики, им нужен контекст

Comment: Бд SQL, хранятся в папке asset, они не большие и их всего пару штук. Подскажите как положить их в папку asset с метками языка?

Comment: назвать их в духе base_ru.base :) В коде получать локаль и из нее пытаться решить какая подходит больше всего. А вообще лучше в любом случае при первом запуске спрашивать какой язык дать

Comment: В папке assets лежит 2 базы, user_en.db и user_ru.db, в values-ru  в файле string.xml прописал строку db_name = user_ru.db . В клласе DB_HELPER указал строку для db_name   при старье приложение слетает

Comment: private static String DB_NAME = getResource().getString(R.string.строка_из_ресурса); Такой вариант не работает.

Comment: Вам вообще удается подключиться к базе из assset'ов? Возникает ощущение, что нет. Тогда сначала с этим вопросом разберитесь. Вы не можете подключиться к базе в асссетах, надо скопировать ее из ассетов на диск, и оттуда открывать

Comment: Я обновил вопрос, добавил код, проблема в private static DB_NAME   не получается присвоить ему ресурс с именем базы

Comment: Обновил ответ выше

Comment: Сделал через конструктор, все получилось, спасибо.